# override retain/release under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have an ARC enabled application that using a MRC(non-ARC) static library. In the static library, `retain`/`release` are overridden to provide some custom weak ref/cache behavior (`[super retain/release]` is called of course). The problem is that since `retain`/`release` are not allowed in ARC-enabled code, is it OK to use classes that override `retain`/`release` in ARC-enabled code? For now it seems to be working well, but I am not sure if this relies on undefined behavior which may break in the future.

Also what is the reason to forbid overriding `retain`/`release`? Is it because some special optimization was done by the compiler that bypasses the message binding process to speed up the method call? I know that `_objc_storeStrong` calls are generated by the compiler that do the reference counting, so does this mean that the overridden `retain`/`release` are not guaranteed to be called under ARC?

Comment: ARC just maintains memory management by itself, i.e. in simple language it puts retain/release code automatically according to scope of object. So, as far as dont worry about library which is not ARC enabled, it will not create any issues in future..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the classes are compiled without ARC (which you can control on a file by file basis;  go to Build Phases and add `-fno-objc-arc` as a flag to any file that should be compiled MRR in an otherwise ARC'd project), then the MRR compiled classes can override retain/release/autorelease to their heart's content.

Retain/release/autorelease are verboten under ARC because ARC is designed to handle all of the memory management for you at compile time while also forcing you to separate memory management from other roles that seemingly can be piled onto memory management, but really don't belong there.

For example, the most typical override of `release` involves checking the `retainCount` and, if it is 2, then the transition to 1 means "put this object back into a cache for later retrieval" whereas the cache is responsible for the final retained reference to the object.

It works, but it is horribly fragile and there are better solutions that do not involve colluding caching with memory management.

Answer (score -4):

overriding of retain/release is incorrect. But if you need it:

```
-(id)retain
{
   NSIncrementExtraRefCount(self);
    return self;
}

-(void)release
{
    if(NSDecrementExtraRefCountWasZero(self))
    {
         NSDeallocateObject(self);
    }
}

-(id)autorelease
{  // Add the object to the autorelease pool
    [NSAutoreleasePool addObject:self];
    return self;
}
```

I haven't tested them for ARC. And an original article:
[link](http://it-interview.ru/voprosy-i-otvety-na-sobesedovanii-dlya-ios-razrabotchika-3/)

Comment: You can't override retain/release in ARC.   And, even if you could, this does not answer the question.

Comment: You could, but that doesn't answer OP's question.   The library *already* overrides `retain`/`release` with a custom implementation.   The OP doesn't need instructions on how to override `retain`/`release`, the OP asked specifically why it was broken under ARC and what to do about it.  Which I explained above.

Comment: look at the beginning of my post. I have already wrote that it is incorrect, but here is an example from another website. What should I do?

Comment: If you can't answer the OP's question, then don't answer at all. There are tons of questions about UIKit details that I pass by exactly because I can't answer them.  In fact, I often search for an answer to a question, end up with a Q/A pair on SO, and upvote both the question and the answer because it was helpful!

Comment: That's an awfully long time to take offense to someone's comment. If you disagree, fine, but telling someone what to do with their *life* doesn't make you any better.